# Modulus in Python's slicing

Tags: python

How can you fix the following code?

I want to get the slice of elements that are *i mod 5 == 1*.

```
data = "8|9|8|9|8|9|8|9|9|8|9|8|9|8|9|8" 
arra = map(int,data.split("|"))  

sums += [sum(arra[i % 5==1:(i + 4) % 5==1])         // Problem here
        for i in range(0, len(arra), 4)]
```

Comment: Stylistically, is there a reason you are converting your data from a string, instead of just starting with `arra = 8,9,8,9,8,9,8,9,9,8,9,8,9,8,9,8`?  Also `arra` is a strange choice of variable name.  `array` is neither a reserved word nor a builtin in python (the structure you're thinking of is either called a `list` or `tuple`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sums += sum(arra[1::5])
```

And it's spelled `array`. ;-)

Comment: I had no idea you could do this. Awesome!

Comment: Further documentation can be found under the term "slicing."

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
sums = sum(arra[1::5])
```

If you use +=, Python spects that the name sums is alreadey accesible:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    sums += sum(arra[1::5])
NameError: name 'sums' is not defined